# How to call a method from a keypress c#, windows form

Tags: c#

Can call the method below from a keypress event to validate the textbox input?

```
/// <summary> method Validate
/// return the boolean value if the passed Calculation Line passes all formatting requirements.
///
///Check that all characters are 0-9, +-/*, = #.  
///Check that there is only one operator and that it is at the start of the Calculation Line.
/// </summary>
public static bool Validate(string calcString)
{
    bool result = true;
    int calcFirstOpPos;
    int calcLastOpPos;

    calcString = calcString.Replace(" ", ""); //Remove any spaces entered e.g. calculations imported from file have spaces between operator and value
    if (calcString != "")
    {
        foreach (char calcChar in calcString)
        {
            calcFirstOpPos = calcString.IndexOf(calcChar);
            calcLastOpPos = calcString.LastIndexOf(calcChar);
            if (calcChar != '.' && calcChar != '\r' && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.plus && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.divide && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.times && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.minus && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.subtotal && CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) != Operator.total && !char.IsDigit(calcChar)) //If not one of these it fails
            {
                result = false;
            }

            else if (calcLastOpPos - calcFirstOpPos > 0 && (CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) == Operator.plus || CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) == Operator.divide || CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) == Operator.times || CalcLine.CharToOp(calcChar) == Operator.minus)) //Test for duplicate operators
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/key-press-cs.htm

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: You could call it in the key press event handler, but what's the point? You can't cancel that event anyway. A better place would probably be on key down. also, it seems like this is validating the entire text and not just a single char, so perhaps it's better to use it in the leave event, when the textbox lost focus.